# Spring Kafka - How to set Commit Async property

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, yaml, spring-kafka

I am trying to set the property for allowing commitAsync() to be called from the KafkaMessageListenerContainer:

```
if (this.containerProperties.isSyncCommits()) {
    this.consumer.commitSync(commits);
}
else {
    this.consumer.commitAsync(commits, is.commitCallback);
}
```

Is there a way to set this in my application.yml file? I was able to set ack-mode to BATCH but I cannot find a way to have the container properties have syncCommits set to false.

Answer (score 1):

That property is not currently exposed as a boot property that can be configured in YAML.

You can override Boot's default `kafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` bean to perform additional configuration of the containers.